# In VS2010 is there a way to correct the cursor icon from getting stuck on pointer without restarting the page?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I am working along in VS2010 and moving code around to make more functions and less clutter, so I copy/paste nine times out of ten my mouse cursor "locks up" and it gets stuck on the arrow pointer rather than the | for text, which is only mildly annoying when you are trying to copy/paste a lot of code around. It clears up whenever I close the file and reopen it, but it interrupts my work flow. Has anyone run into this before, if so, did you figure out how to fix it without closing the file?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do the arrow keys work at all when this happens?

Comment: First I heard of this.  Post to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: The up and down arrow keys do still work. Why do you ask?

Comment: You're right this is really annoying. Arrow-cursor makes it difficult to select the right text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this as a report to MS. I am paraphrasing here, "it is in the bug list and we will look into it."

The only solution is to close the file and re-open it. If MS replies with anything else I will post it here.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report? I hate this issue -_-.